# Memory used by RAMDirectory

Tags: lucene

when using lucene 3.5.0,
After indexing into a RAMDirectory,
is there a simple way to know how much memory does it use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html#sizeInBytes%28%29

> **sizeInBytes**
>
> `public final long sizeInBytes()`
>
> Return total size in bytes of all files in this directory. This is currently quantized to RAMOutputStream.BUFFER_SIZE.